# Windows Server 2008 past system crashes?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory-dump

Just wondering does anybody know the default location for .mdmp/.hdmp files on Windows Server 2008, or a quick way of checking what applications on the system have crashed in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .mdmp/.hdmp files seem to be located here on Windows Server 2008: **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue**

You may be able to find out about what applications have crashed on your system by exporting the system event log as a .txt file and searching this for the word "terminated".